# Broadcast receiver reaches to main activity although main activity is killed

Tags: android, static, alarmmanager, broadcast

My situation is a little bit different. I am developing an API for my application so that third party developers can use my application. That's why my API codes are nothing but a library like Facebook SDK (import it and use it.)
In this API, I am using alarmManager and BroadCastReceivers and I need the context of the  third party developer's Main Activity to make API work.
That's why I wrote a sample app to accomplish that and I sent the activity and context to my API as my API's static variables.
When I start Sample App, it works well although it goes to onDestroy State.

However, after I clear my application from the memory (from application tray), it blows up because of some null static variables when background receiver receives something.

Yes, I can use sharedPreferences for static variables defined as boolean, string etc. 
What about activity and context of main activity which defined as static ?
How to initialize them ?

OR when background receiver receives something , it automatically creates an instance of main activity ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to unregister your receiver in onPause() instead of onDestroy() method of activity like this,

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

Comment: But I want receiver work in background , dont want to stop it . If it receives something, it tries to reach some variables in the app . But app is already killed .